# Retrieve data between two dates in Android SQLite

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data between two dates in Android `SQLite` I used one function in `SQLiteAdapter` class. My function is

```
public void history(String startdate,String enddate) {  
   Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ KK_AIRLINEBOOK + 
                    " WHERE " + KEY_Bookingdate + 
                    " BETWEEN " + startdate + " AND " + enddate , null);        
}
```

However it doesn't work it shows syntax error near `AND`

Comment: What is the exact query you are sending to the database? Please edit it into your question. (Also, please use the `code` button for code formatting in the future - see my edit).

Comment: @halfer actuly i want to show booking history to user like if user want to know his booking details between particular two dates........what query i need to pass??? please please help me :( :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put literals

```
public void history(String startdate,String enddate) {  
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ KK_AIRLINEBOOK + 
                " WHERE " + KEY_Bookingdate + 
                " BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'", null);        
}
```

However it is better if you use selectionArgs

```
public void history(String startdate,String enddate) {  
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ KK_AIRLINEBOOK + 
                " WHERE " + KEY_Bookingdate + 
                " BETWEEN ?  AND ?", new String[]{startdate, enddate});        
}
```